# MYSQL Query statements based on PHP radio buttons

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, conditional-statements, radio-button

I have group of radio buttons:

```
<div id="navbarval">
    <input type="radio" name="selectionval"  onchange="this.form.submit();" value="users" checked> CATEGORY USERS
    <input type="radio" name="selectionval"  onchange="this.form.submit();" value="avgspends"> AVERAGE SPENDS
    <input type="radio" name="selectionval"  onchange="this.form.submit();" value="totalspends" > TOTAL SPENDS
    <input type="radio" name="selectionval"  onchange="this.form.submit();" value="percapita" > PER CAPITA SPENDS
</div>
```

based on the user selection I am trying to fetch the mysql data.  My php codes so far is as follows:

```
$query = if ($_POST['selectionval'] == "users"){
            "SELECT users,sum(categ) as categ FROM cktable group by users";  
          }
```

I am getting the following error:

> Parse error: parse error in /Users/dynamo/Sites/newvan/accessories.php on line 210

I want to extend this with else if for all the other radio buttons to alter mysql select query and hence the need for if condition.

i tried passing the select statement directly:

```
$query = "SELECT users,sum(categ) as categ FROM cktable group by users";
```

this runs without any error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Assign inside the `if`, or use ternary.

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['selectionval']) && $_POST['selectionval'] == "users"){ // run the query }`

Comment: what and where is `$categ` assigned/declared?

Comment: @RamRaider yeah; that syntax stands not to work `as {$categ}`; quite odd. The question is starting to look unclear.

Comment: *Hold on there cowboy...* `<div id="navbarval" method="POST">`?? - divs do not have methods, forms do. I think you're looking to use ajax for this, if anything.

Comment: Thank you all...and pardon me for errors....today is my day 3 with php mysql....i have removed the method and $categ is actually categ.  The original code is as follows: `"SELECT {$filt},sum({$categ}) as {$categ} FROM {$table} group by {$filt}";`  The variables were declared within PHP and they are working without trouble if I use it as a standalone code.

Comment: By the way I tried all 4 answers and still have the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You used wrong syntax. Change your code as below.

```
if (isset($_POST['selectionval']) && $_POST['selectionval'] == "users"){
    $query = "SELECT users,sum(categ) as {$categ} FROM cktable group by users";  
}
```

Or use [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) :

`$query = (isset($_POST['selectionval']) && $_POST['selectionval'] == "users") ? "SELECT users,sum(categ) as {$categ} FROM cktable group by users" : '';`

Comment: the first one stands to fail on initial page load. Best to use `isset()`. This comment based on the initial post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43762506/1

Answer (score 0):

Try changing :

```
$query = if ($_POST['selectionval'] == "users"){
            "SELECT users,sum(categ) as {$categ} FROM cktable group by users";  
          }
```

to

```
if ($_POST['selectionval'] == "users"){
            $query = "SELECT users,sum(categ) as {$categ} FROM cktable group by users";  
          }
```

Comment: the first one stands to fail on initial page load. Best to use `isset()`.

Answer (score 0):

To extend the solution, you can use a map of queries based on your radio values.

Ex:

```
$queries = array(
  'value1' => 'SELECT ...', 
  'value2' => 'SELECT ...',
  'valueN' => 'SELECT ...'
);

$radio_value = $_POST['radio_name'];

if (isset($queries[$radio_value])) {
  $query = $queries[$radio_value];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than numerous `if`,`elseif`,`else` statements a `switch` statement seems, to my mind, much simpler to read. Also, by checking the `Request Method` is set the switch statement will not be executed until the form is submitted.

```
<?php

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['selectionval'] ) ){

        $sql=false;
        $categ='---what is $categ---';


        $selection=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'selectionval', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

        switch( strtolower( $selection ) ){
            case 'users':
                $sql="select `users`, sum( `categ` ) as '{$categ}' from `cktable` group by `users`";
            break;
            case 'avgspends':
                $sql="select.....";
            break;
            case 'totalspends':
                $sql="select.....";
            break;
            case 'percapita':
                $sql="select.....";
            break;
        }



        if( $sql ){
            /* execute query */
            #$db->query( $sql );
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Better have a second look there `<div id="navbarval" method="POST">` ;-) [as per my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43762377/mysql-query-statements-based-on-php-radio-buttons#comment74566459_43762377)

Comment: Me neither at first, then noticed it after a few more glares and stares *lol*